# Convert SQL to LINQ using Group by and Sum

Tags: sql, asp.net, linq, c#-3.0

I'm new using LINQ and I'm trying to convert this sql query to LINQ without succes.
Help please

```
select z.des_zona,s.des_sector , sum(sueldo)as Sueldos 
from Personas p
inner join Sectores s on s.cod_sector=p.cod_sector
inner join Zonas z on z.cod_zona=p.cod_zona
group by z.des_zona,s.des_sector
```

Comment: A good start would be to find an O/R mapper that supports LINQ.

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework? "I'm trying to convert this sql query to LINQ without succes" Show us your attempt.

Comment: Yes, I want to use it on ASP. Net

Comment: ASP.Net is irrelevant here. It's more relevant to show what you tried and why it was "without success". We can't help you if we have to assume everything.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming your entities like this

```
public class Persona
{
    public int sueldo { get; set; }
    public string cod_sector { get; set; }
    public string cod_zona { get; set; }
}

public class Sectore
{
    public string cod_sector { get; set; }
}

public class Zona
{
    public string cod_zona { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the linq

```
Personas.Join(Sectores, l => l.cod_sector, r => r.cod_sector, (l, r) => new { Persona = l, r.cod_sector })
    .Join(Zonas, l => l.Persona.cod_zona, r => r.cod_zona, (l, r) => new { l.Persona.sueldo, l.cod_sector, r.cod_zona })
    .GroupBy(i => new { i.cod_zona, i.cod_sector })
    .Select(g => new
    {
        g.Key.cod_zona,
        g.Key.cod_sector,
        Sueldos = g.Sum(i => i.sueldo)
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: One of the main benefits of an ORM like Entity Framework is that we can use navigation properties and, therefore, hardly ever need joins in LINQ.

Comment: Yes, it's hard to use pure linq working with multiple join.

Comment: Well, then don't.